# JSLint command line causes "filename or extension too long" java error

Tags: java, processbuilder, createprocess

I've been tasked with trying to get a JSLint job working that outputs to an XML file,  but I've hit a bit of a road block. I am running into an error that returns with "CreateProcess error=206, the filename or extension is too long."

My intention is to try to grab everything that is within a folder without having to split it up into separate filepaths, although I'm thinking that might be what I have to do.

The basic ant target I have is as follows:

```
<target name="d">
  <fileset dir="../" id="src.files">
    <include name="**/*.js"/>
  </fileset>
  <pathconvert pathsep=" " refid="src.files" property="spacedelim"/>
<exec executable="java" output="jslint.xml">
  <arg line="-jar jslint4java-2.0.2.jar --report xml ${spacedelim}" />
</exec>
</target>
```

spacedelim returns a space delimited list of all of the files that end in js inside of the folder with the js files. If I paste the list of files that ${spacedelim} contains, then it works fine, even when calling the ant target... So I'm really not sure what to make of that.

Here is the full error:

```
BUILD FAILED
D:\dev\features\2011.2\webui\wmd\webclient\jslint4java-2.0.2\build.xml:53: Execu
te failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Exec
ute.java:862)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at     org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 24 more

Total time: 4 seconds
```

Thanks for any insight anyone may have to offer!